# Should I use template for checking emptiness for string and vector?

Tags: c++

I have to check if the members of a class are empty or not. The class is reading from a json file some values and if some members are empty that means the json is bad formatted. Until now I had to check just the emptiness of string, And I have done it using a function:

```
void ConfigFile::checkEmptyness(const std::string& strIn, const std::string& memberNameIn, const std::string& pathIn)
{
    if (strIn.empty())
    {
        throw ConfigFileException(emptyStringOrGetFailedMsg(pathIn, memberNameIn));
    }
}
```

Now I have to modify the application to read also an vector of floats from the json. I have found how to read the vector from json:

```
for (auto& item : tmpPT.get_child(path))
{
    float label = item.second.get_value< float >();
    checkNegativity< float >(label, "classifierSearchedClass", path);
    m_classifierSearchedClass.push_back(label);
}
```

but I am thinking to verifying if it is also empty. I can create an overloaded function `checkEmptyness` that has a vector parameter. So, my question is:

Shall I create a template, or just an overloaded function?

If creating a template, doing it like this:

```
template< typename T>
void ConfigFile::checkEmptyness(const T& arrIn, const std::string& memberNameIn, const std::string& pathIn)
{
    if (arrIn.empty())
    {
        throw ConfigFileException(emptyStringOrGetFailedMsg(pathIn, memberNameIn));
    }
}
```

is a good way to go, or using overloading is better?

Comment: what is compile error? [this](http://ideone.com/X8zNWz) works

Comment: Ooops, sorry about that, it was another error (edited)... Anyway, that is correct?

Comment: I think so, if later there are types which does not work, you can specialise for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good way to go, since it obeys [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).